# How to use the model.predict for data after training tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow

i followed the guide found here(regression): 
https://stackabuse.com/tensorflow-2-0-solving-classification-and-regression-problems/
using this dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVmGNx6cbfvRHC_DvF12ZL3wGLSHD9f_/view

and ended up with this code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'path')
X = data.iloc[:, 0:4].values
y = data.iloc[:, 4].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)


input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(50, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
dense_layer_3 = Dense(25, activation='relu')(dense_layer_2)
output = Dense(1)(dense_layer_3)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error" , optimizer="adam", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])


history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)


from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

pred_train = model.predict(X_train)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train,pred_train)))

pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,pred)))
```

Everything works and the model gets trained, but how do i actually use it? I want to input 4 intergers and in return get the prediction. So for example take the array [9, 4554, 1950, 0.634] and then get the predicted value. No matter what i do the model won't accept the data i am using.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Main Problem which you are facing as per my understanding is dimension Because you insert [9,...,0.634] which of shape (4,) it mean 1D while X_test,X_train require to be 2D as per documentationo you have to convert 1D to 2D.

## How You Convert

```
import numpy as np
X_test=[9,...,0.634]
X_test=np.array(X_test)
X_test=X_test.reshape(1,4)
model.predict(X_test)
```

s[image]